# How to set acl on my fstab file?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, permissions, access-control-list

I would like to enable acl on my remote server.
So I type the following command `df` to know on which partition I am :
Here is the result :

```
 Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
    /dev/simfs      26214400 1202356  25012044   5% /
    none               52432    1048     51384   2% /run
    none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
    none              262144       0    262144   0% /run/shm
```

Now, here is my /etc/fstab file :

```
proc  /proc       proc    defaults    0    0
none  /dev/pts    devpts  rw      0    0
```

2 questions :

- In which line I have to add ',acl' and
- then I would have to remount my partition using `mount -o remount **folder?**` I don't know which folder : `/proc` or `/dev/pts` ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a [**VPS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server)? If so, you probably don't have access to the real filesystem of the host system. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm using a VPS indeed. I would like to enable acl on my filesystem, for setting the right permissions on my cache and logs folder for my symfony2 project as described here : http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/installation.html (in the "Setting up permissions" section).

Comment: So it's impossible to enable acl on my VPS ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

1. Modify your fstab like this:

   `proc  /proc       proc    defaults,errors=remount-ro,acl   0    0`
2. Type `sudo mount / -o remount.`
3. Check if acl works correctly. Type `getfacl any_folder/`. This command should show permissions of the folder. If yes, everything's fine.
4. Specifically for symfony2 installation: go to your symfony2 project folder. Use `getfacl app/cache` and `getfacl app/logs` to view the permissions of those folders. You will see what kinds of the permissions are held by your groups. Then use setfacl on the group that you want to change. For example, `setfacl -m other:rwx app/cache`. Use setfacl for both folders.

Answer (score -1):

I hope the below url will help you,

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1414003

Comment: Please summarize, the given link can break at any time.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers have content, not pointers to content. This may theoretically answer the question however, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This post will be removed if not improved. Thank you!